# Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value. Que erro é esse?

Tags: php, mysql

Nessa página eu seleciono a id do livro para exibi-lo e depois atualizo o campo visitas, incrementando-o.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}
$livros = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT nome, descricao, imagem, download, 
visitas FROM livro WHERE id='$id'")or die(mysqli_error($conexao));
if(mysqli_num_rows($livros) <= 0)
{
    echo "<h2>Banco de dados não retornou nenhum valor</h2>";
}
while($res_livros = mysqli_fetch_array($livros))
{
    $nome = $res_livros['0'];
    $descricao = $res_livros['1'];
    $imagem = $res_livros['2'];
    $download = $res_livros['3'];
    $visitas = $res_livros['4'];
}
?>
<h1><?=$nome;?></h1>
<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="uploads/livros/<?=$imagem;?>">
    <figure>
    <img class="alignright" width="200" src="uploads/livros/<?=$imagem;?>"/>
      <figcaption><a id="download" href="<?=$download?>">Download</a> 
      </figcaption>
   </figure>
</a>
<h3><?=$descricao?></h3>
</section>
</div>

<?php

if(isset($visitas))
{
    $add_visitas = $visitas + 1;
    $up_visitas = mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE livro SET visitas = 
    '$add_visitas' WHERE id='$id'")or die(mysqli_error($conexao));
}

?>
```

To postando o código todo mas o erro acontece é aqui em baixo, no UPDATE livro.

Galera, agora eu resolvi mandar imprimir a id aqui embaixo e apareceu a id do livro +".php", assim: 106.php. Por isso tá dando Boolean, mas de onde tá saindo esse ".php"? No banco de dados tá só o número normal.

Eu resolvi o problema aqui, era besteira minha, obviamente eu passei o .php junto com a id pra página mas por algum motivo o SELECT não teve nenhum conflito com isso, mas o UPDATE sim.

Comment: Retire as aspas simples de `'$add_visitas'` e teste. Mas vc poderia incrementar com `UPDATE livro SET visitas = visitas+1 WHERE...`

Comment: Que tipo de dado é `visitas` no banco de dados? Já que é um contador, deveria ser `INT`

Comment: É inteiro mesmo.

Comment: Então, use `visitas = visitas+1` que é mais simples.

Comment: Eu fiz, o erro persiste, muito estranho esse erro cara.

Comment: Qual é a linha que dá o erro?

Comment: Dá uma olhada no comentário que adicionei ali encima, eu imprimi a id do livro e tá dando "106.ph", ao invés de 106.

Comment: Antes do último UPDATE.

Comment: Eu posso tipo fazer uma gambiarra e tirar esse .php da string, mas agora eu quero saber como isso foi parar aí.